# Advanced search: Hide some of the options

Tags: joomla-3.x, search, smartsearch

I am setting up a site to use the Joomla Smary Search component (com_finder).

The component is working well, but I have a question about the advanced search options.

When the advanced search options are enabled in the component, it shows a set of drop-down fields under the main search field, which allows the user to filter their search by Author, Category, Language and Type.

For my site, we don't need all of those options -- we don't need the Author option because the author isn't shown on articles and isn't relevant to the end user. We also don't need language, as the site is not multi-lingual.

However I can't find how to turn these fields off without switching off the whole advanced search block. I would like to keep the other options.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this? I'm considering hacking around in the template, but that seems a bit drastic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I found it!

For the benefit of anyone else who can't see how to do this...

I was looking for it in the options when configuring the menu item, and in the component options in global config.

In fact, you need to look in the component itself. Go to "Components" / "Smart Search", and then pick the "Content Maps" section. You'll see that your content has been indexed against Author, Category, Language and Type. Simply un-tick the ones you don't want and they will stop showing up as drop-down options.

Easy when you know how  :-)